# Abel's integrate equation (Laplace transform)

Tags: laplace-transform

I am stuck in my textbook; it states:
Given Abel's integral equation:
$$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac {\phi(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha}} d\tau$$
It is clear that the Laplace transform can be represented as follows:
$$\bar{\phi }(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}s^{1-\alpha}\bar{f}(s)$$
Perhaps for most readers it is clear, but I can't get to it. Perhaps I am confused by the number of $\phi's$ and $\alpha's$. Perhaps somebody is able to put me on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 4 hours of thinking and trying, I think I found the solution. I hope it is correct, if not, please don't hesitate to correct it.
The RHS of the equation is the convolution of $\phi (t)$ and $\frac{1}{t^{-\alpha}}$ and so$$F(s) = \mathcal{L}[f(t)] = \mathcal{L}[\phi(t)]\mathcal{L}\bigg[\frac{1}{t^\alpha}\bigg] =\bar{\phi }(s)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {e^{-st}}{t^{\alpha}}dt$$By taking $s=x>0$ and putting $\tau = xt$ to obtain$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {e^{-xt}}{t^{\alpha}} = x^{-(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \tau^{(1-\alpha)-1}e^{-\tau}d\tau$$
$$=  x^{-(1-\alpha)}\Gamma (1-\alpha)$$

If we continue this we note that:
$$\mathcal{L}\bigg[\frac{1}{t^\alpha}\bigg] = s^{-(1-\alpha)}\Gamma (1-\alpha)$$
Hence:
$$\bar{\phi }(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}s^{1-\alpha}\bar{f}(s)$$